# assigning distinct Field's to each element in pydantic Union

Tags: pydantic

How do I assign a different `pydantic.Field()` to each type within a union?  In the example below, the `Field(pattern=...)` should only apply to the `str`.

```
class Foo(BaseModel):
    bar: str | FooDetail = Field(pattern=r'[bar]+') # but this should only apply to str

class FooDetail(BaseModel):
    baz: int
    fob: float
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Annotated` to specify both the type and the `Field`, and then still create a union from that with `FooDetail`:

```
from typing_extensions import Annotated

class Foo(BaseModel):
    bar: Annotated[str, Field(pattern=r'[bar]+')] | FooDetail

class FooDetail(BaseModel):
    baz: int
    fob: float
```